# Logic of Django's per-view cache

Tags: django, caching

URLconf:

```
...
(r'^entry/(.*)', 'myapp.views.entry_view'),
...
```

View function

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

def entry_view(request,entry_id):
    if request.user.is_staff:
        retrun entry_staff(request,entry_id)
    else:
        return entry_user(request,entry_id)

# don't cache this view
def entry_staff(request,entry_id):
    ....

@cache_page
def entry_user(request,entry_id):
    ....
```

My questions:

1. I make a guess about the logic of django's pre-view cache: It's like a Python **dict**, URL as key, rendered HTML as value. The decorated view will first check if the URL is in that dict, making an **internal redirect** is key found. Am I right?
2. Well the code before work? My situation is, contents for staff users always contain something dynamic, no way to cache; contents for anonymous users are not prone to change, so cache should be made.

Comment: You need to provide the cache timeout; so `@cache.page(60*30)` for 30 minutes. Other than that, what is the problem that you are facing with this code?

Comment: Thank you for mention that. And I assume if my guess is right, this code should work. Doubt comes from that fact that `entry_user` and `entry_staff` doesn't face the URL directly, and they share same URLs.

Comment: They can't share the same URLs; only the first one that matches the pattern will be called (url patterns are evaluated in the order they are written, and the first match stops evaluation of the rest of the patterns). If there is view method that is not being called; then `cache_page` will have no effect.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Please see my code. Only `entry_view` is mapped to a url pattern, and it will decide which _actual_ view function to call. And `cache_page` decorater only decorates `entry_user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually add items to the cache using the [low level cache API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api).

In this case you won't use the decorator; instead your other methods will simply return data to your mapped method and in the loop you will set any values that have expired from the cache:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def entry_staff(entry_id):
    return 'staff only value'

def entry_user(entry_id):
    return 'value to cache'

@login_required
def entry_view(request,entry_id):
    if request.user.is_staff:
        value = entry_staff(entry_id)
    else:
        value = cache.get('key','NO-VALUE')
        if value == 'NO-VALUE':
           # cache expired
           value = entry_user(entry_id)
           cache.set('key', value, 30*60)
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'value': value})
```

Comment: Thanks. But if as I did, will clients get responds as I expect?

Comment: Yes, but sometimes clients complain anyway :)